# Are these features possible to develop with a firefox extention?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, add-on

I want to create a Firefox extension. I would ask for the feasibility of my idea.

I have a PHP page show a list of emails with open on browser link next to it,
when I click that button, the following will happen:

1. Create new browser profile on the fly (if it does not already
   exist)
2. The profile will load the following information from our application database through XML or API.

   2.1. proxy settings

   2.2. user agent

   2.3. autofill information related to that account like username, password, date of birth, and other information related to that account username.
3. We want to be able to open multiple profiles (tabs) in the same window.
4. Is there a limit of profiles that Firefox can handle?
5. How long do you thing it will take for an experience extension developer to do this (we provide xml)

I would know if that is possible and the guidelines to do it.

Comment: From my understanding of your limited description, It can be done with the exception of opening a separate Firefox Profiles in tabs of the same window. Generally, a Firefox profile is associated with one running instance of the Firefox executable. Depending on exactly what you desire for that, it *might* be faked sufficiently well for your purpose. Given that you want the profiles open in additional tabs, I assume you want the profiles associated with the same user account that is currently running the extension? As to profile # limits, I have not checked. How many were you thinking you want?

Comment: this looks more like a job advertisement than a technical question

Comment: I believe it'd only take a couple of days for an "experienced extension developer" to write something like this. Mostly a matter of finding the right APIs to do X, Y and Z. I don't know any way of having tabs in the same window associated with different profiles, but you can easily open new browser instances with different profiles through the command line (`-P "path/to/profile" --no-remote`).